# Redirect guest if he tries to access a specific page

Tags: redirect

While I'm developing a website and doing some testing I would like to block access to non-admin (and eventually non-editors) to specific pages such as the woocommerce shop and related pages.

Is there a way, without using plugins, in the `functions.php` to check:

```
$list_of_blocked_pages = [ 'shop', 'cart', 'checkout', 'etc...' ];

if ( current_page_is_in( $list_of_blocked_pages ) && !admin && !editor ) {
    redirect_to_page( $url );
}
```

Comment: Have you looked into https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags?

Comment: @Beee My problem is not with what conditions to use, but where? Is there a specific `hook` to use in the `functions.php` file? Essentially I would like to know what is the right and clean way to do that.

Comment: @mark-kaplun and @fuxia may I ask why you removed tags such as `woocommerce` and `routing` as these are key points in answering this questions? Woocommerce pages cannot be "password protected" or made "private" through the page's publishing options. This issue might have also been solved on the `routing` level I guess. Your clarification could help me in being more precise and correct next time.

Comment: many people ignore the WC tag, as WC is off topic but still generate a lot of noice. your question was just very partially specific to WC...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [template_redirect](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect) action to redirect Specific users based on your terms. 
This action hook executes just before WordPress determines which template page to load. It is a good hook to use if you need to do a redirect with full knowledge of the content that has been queried.

You can use [is_page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/) function to check weather the current page is in your list of pages or not.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_to_specific_page' );

function redirect_to_specific_page() {
    if ( is_page('slug') && ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        wp_redirect( 'http://www.example.dev/your-page/', 301 ); 
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I saw that you use the 'template_redirect' action hook which looks more appropriate than the one I used in my answer, therefore you you get the point! ;)

Comment: WP codex is your friend. Try looking there before searching anywhere.

Comment: I tried, trust me, but for some reason I couldn't find anything helpful. Was getting more blogs and stackoverflow solutions/questions to other stuff than this specific one. Also I was wondering if there was some specific wordpress hook to handle `routing`, which I didn't found.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving like this:

```
function block_woocommerce_pages_for_guest() {
    $blocked_pages =  is_woocommerce() || is_shop() || is_cart() || is_checkout() || is_account_page() || is_wc_endpoint_url();
    if( !current_user_can('administrator') && !current_user_can('editor') && $blocked_pages ) {
        wp_redirect('/');
        exit;
    } 
}
add_action( 'wp', 'block_woocommerce_pages_for_guest', 8 );
```

This way all non-admin and non-editor will be redirected to the homepage.

Comment: You might want to consider hook `template_redirect ` as this hook "fires before determining which template to load" - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_redirect/